# activeTintColor does not change color of tab icons in react native

Tags: react-native

Below is tabBarOption's implementation in react native app.

```
tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#7364F1',
            inactiveTintColor: '#000',
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 12,
              },
        },
```

I have added `activeTintColor` to change tint color of active tab, but it only changes the label's color on tabs not the icon's color on iOS simulator. Would appreciate any help for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use -> activeBackgroundColor prop in  to change the active tab's Color as follows :

tabBarOptions: {
            activeBackgroundColor: 'green',
        },

Comment: It changes background color of the tab, not the tab icon's color. I want to change tabIcon's color